# Dictionary<KeyType,ValueType> является ли потокобезопасным для чтения?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Является ли `Dictionary<KeyType,ValueType>` потокобезопасным для чтения и перебора значений?

То есть записи в этот Dictionary не будет (инициализируется только при запуске проекта), и хочу понять можно ли его использовать в контексте singleton сервиса в ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

> Thread Safety
>
> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified.

то есть

> Потокобезопасность
>
> ... поддерживает несколько  одновременных операций чтения, постольку
>   поскольку данные не изменяются.

Comment: Меня вот это смущает  >> Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure.

Comment: Я считаю, что это относится к перебору, во время которого словарь изменяется.

Comment: По идее так должно быть... но в тексте вроде нету слов что это относится именно к enumeration с изменениями, вроде как звучит что для любого перебора.

Comment: Хотя там дальше расшифровка идёт, и вроде как то что вы написали поясняется.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043615/thread-safety-of-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, сам по себе словарь является потокобезопасным для случая, когда у вас есть лишь операции чтения из разных потоков. Однако для случая, когда вам ещё нужна инициализация, необходимо учитывать возможные «гонки» между инициализирующим потоком, и потоком, который читает уже инициализированный словарь.

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
var dict = Dictionary<K, V>();
dict[k1] = v1; // инициализация
GlobalAccessibleDict = dict; // публикация
```

Я проштудировал [спецификацию](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#execution-order) и не нашёл пункта, который запрещал бы компилятору переставить инициализацию и публикацию, ведь с точки зрения публикующего потока от перестановки этих присваиваний смысл кода не меняется. Таким образом, с точки зрения другого, читающего потока инициализация может произойти *слишком поздно*. Итак, судя по всему, с точки зрения языка этот паттерн *неправильный*, и может привести к чтению другим потоком недоинициализированного словаря. Для того, чтобы быть уверенныйм, необходимо использовать `lock` (или, возможно публикацию через volatile-поле).

[Обновление: Майкрософт опубликовала [черновики документации](https://github.com/VSadov/runtime/blob/memModel/docs/design/coreclr/botr/memory-model.md#object-assignment) о модели памяти, откуда следует, что паттерн таки *правильный*, публикация служит барьером, и дополнительная синхронизация не нужна.]

С другой стороны, с точки зрения имплементации в Microsoft .NET, статья Joe Duffy [*CLR 2.0 memory model*](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/10/clr-20-memory-model/) утверждает, что в имплементации .NET 2.0

> Rule 2: All stores have release semantics, i.e. no load or store may move after one.

то есть, перестановки записей в переменные недопустимы. Если я правильно понял этот текст, это означает, что гонка, описанная мной, невозможна, и инициализация закончится строго до публикации. Поэтому с хорошей долей вероятности в текущей реализации (а модель памяти .NET 4.0 вроде бы не слабее) в вашем подходе всё хорошо. (Я не нашёл, однако, ничего про порядок актуализации данных в других потоках, так что тонкости остаются.)

Comment: У меня ещё может быть ситуации переинициализации словаря. Если проще я роли храню в словаре и они находятся в памяти постоянно (тут смысла нету объяснять почему). Но админ может поменять роли, значит мне их надо будет переинициализировать. Вот с этим тоже думал сегодня. Но тут тоже проблемы быть не должно, так как я просто новый словарь создам и запишу поверх того что был изначально, и новые запросы будут идти к новому словарю, в то время как если старые ещё что-то обрабатывают там будут старые значения, меня это устраивает.

Comment: По поводу того что вы написали, я понял, но в моём случае тут не должно быть проблемы, так как инициализация и публикация происходит при запуске сайта, а обращения уже гарантированно идут позже.

Comment: Хм... а зачем компилятору менять порядок операций, если это может к таким проблемам приводить...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Если словарь меняется, то тогда вам просто не обойтись без блокировки. Окружайте доступ к меняющимся частям `lock`'ом.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Нет, думаю, вы не поняли. То, что одно действие позже другого по времени, не является гарантией, что данные будут видны в другом потоке. Вы представляете себе, будто данные «медленно летят» в другой поток, и через пару секунд точно долетят. Это не так. В спецификации такой гарантии нигде нет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Формальный ответ — потому что это разрешено спецификацией. Теперь смотрите, зачем это. Оптимизации нужны, потому что они делают программы в сотни раз быстрее. Если бы все оптимизации пытались быть безопасными в многопоточном сценарии, то код был бы намного медленнее, потому что нельзя было бы даже считать переменную в регистр (а вдруг её другой поток поменяет?). Поэтому реально делают так: те немногие переменные, которые разделяются между потоками, вы должны «спасти от проблем» сами при помощи `lock`'ов, а остальные переменные оптимизируются как будто бы потоков не существует.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. Смотрите как у меня. Есть Dictionary с ролями, и всё хорошо. В какой-то момент я делаю перезаливку ролей. Тот dictionary отсаётся как был, но вместо него я записываю новый с новой информацией. Те кто уже получили старый dictionary с ним и отработают. Я думаю тут можно без `lock`-ов обойтись.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин: Ну, опять-таки, без локов нет никакой гарантии, что значение переменной, которое поменялось в одном потоке, поменяется и в другом. Вот вам пример: https://pastebin.com/5gP2Ymje. Откомпилируйте Release (обязательно!) и запустит EXE с командной строки, не из-под Visual Studio. Подумайте над результатом.